# How to do it the Ruby way : Count no. of occurence of a in b

Tags: ruby

This is the snippet of code i'm using now:

```
def countOccurences(a, b)
  #counts the number of occurences of a in b 
  count=0
  cur=0
  while cur < b.length do
    temp=b.index(a, cur)
    if temp == nil
      break
    end
    count=count+1
    cur=temp+a.length
  end
  return count
end
```

Is there any Ruby function that does this? Any functional equivalent? Or anything better?

Comment: Are a and b strings? You may want to make this clear in the question.

Comment: yes they are. sorry to miss it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If a and b are strings:

```
b.scan(a).length
```

Comment: @Jasim: Then you should accept James' answer so he (and you) can get credit.

Comment: Actually a better one would be b.count(a)

Answer (score 4):

The most obvious way

```
enum.find_all {| obj | block } => array
```

plus

```
array.length
```

or you could just do it with a fold

```
enum.inject {| memo, obj | block } => obj
```

Comment: @Steve: I'll have to explore enum. Thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 3):

I'm assuming `b` is an array and `b` is an object to look for in the array.

```
ary = ["foo", "bar", "baz", "foo", "foo", "maz"]
look_for = "foo"

p a.detect {|i| i == look_for }.length
# => 3
```

You could also monkey-patch this into `Array`.

```
class Array
  def occurrences_of(object)
    detect {|i| i == object }.length
  end
end

p ["foo", "bar", "baz", "foo", "foo", "maz"].occurrences_of("foo")
# => 3
```

Answer (score -2):

You just need to loop through the array using each, and through that create an array with the key of "a" and count as a value. Then just return the count.

```
def count_occurences(a, b)
  r = Array.new
  b.eachdo |e|
    if e == a 
      r[e]++
    end
  end
end
```

That should do it!

Comment: Couple of things wrong with this one: a) You're missing a space between "each" and "do". b) Ruby does not have a `++` operator. c) The return value of that method will always be `b` - you probably want to return `r[a]`. c) `r[e]` will only work if e is an integer, so a has to be an integer for this to work. d) Note that elements of r will be initialized to nil, not 0, so incrementing will only work if you initialize to 0 first. e) Since you only access `r[e]` when e==a, you`re only ever accessing one index of r so you could as well use a single integer for counting instead of an array.